# why my switch transition animation disappear when i set another state on the onChange of the mui switch component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

here is the code that on my vscode
the mui version is 5.8.4
react version is 18.2
and the result is that when i setInfo the transition animation of ther switch button not work,and i dont know why

```
import { Box, Typography, Switch, FormControlLabel, FormGroup } from '@mui/material'
import { useState } from 'react'
const SwitchBar = (props) => {
  const { name, content, info, setInfo } = props
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInfo({ ...info, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked })
  }
  return (
    <Box sx={{ bgcolor: '#EFF1F6', borderRadius: '7px', p: '11px 10px', height: '46px', maxWidth: '323px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Typography variant='body14Med'>{content}</Typography>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch name={name} checked={info[name]} onChange={handleChange} />
          }
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </Box>
  )
}
export default function Test () {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({ test: false })
  return (
    <SwitchBar name='test' content={info.test} info={info} setInfo={setInfo} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any error you are getting in the console?

Comment: oh sry, maybe there is something wrong with my local environment, it seems ok right now, thanks for your time